# offset of pagination doesnt show first image

Tags: php, pagination

I am coding pagination, but first element of the page isn't showing. I tried 2 different offsets, but using first, doesn't show one, but using second, it doesn't show two images.

```
offset = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage

offset = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage +1
```

my pagination image gallery code

```
<?php
        $per_page = 12;
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;          //first item to display on this page
    
        
        $files = array_slice(glob("img/*.*"), $start, $per_page);
        $file_count = glob("img/*.*");
        
        for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++){
            $image = $files[$i];
            //print $image ."<br />";
            echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" />';
        }
        $per_page = 12;
        $pages = ceil(count($file_count)/$per_page);
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        
        if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
            header("location: index.php?page=1");
        }else{
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++){
  $image = $files[$i];
  //print $image ."<br />";
  echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" />';
}
```

If i'm looking at this code, 1 of the problems is the fact that you are never calling the first value in the array. The first value of an array is 0.

So your for loop is never reaching the first value. Because $i = 1
You should start with $i = 0 and use count($files-1) to reach the first value.

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($files-1); $i++){
  $image = $files[$i];
  //print $image ."<br />";
  echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" />';
}
```

Comment: Solved the problem? Or do you have another problem?

Comment: Great, glad to be @ your service, could you accept so other users can notice the accepted answer :)